# Is it possible to disable closing in ng-dialog in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

What I am trying is, to disable the action of close in ng-dialog pop up until any other button is clicked.I want to do that until I give some text on input in pop up and click on save button the pop up should not be closed either by into (*) mark

Comment: If I am not wrong then you wants to disable the close button untill from in pop up is not valid, Right?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a template of pop up like below :

```
<button type="button" ng-click="closeThisDialog('button')" ng-disabled="demoForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-default pull-right">x</button>
<br>
<form name="demoForm">
  <h3>Close button disabled untill no input</h3>
  <p>Here input field is required so untill input box is not valid you cannot close the dialoug.</p>
  <p>Once you enter the input close btn will be enabled</p>
  <input ng-model="confirmValue" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="demoForm.$invalid" ng-click="closeThisDialog('button')" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

You can add form in your pop-up template just shown in above template.

Now as per your requirement user should not close the popup until he didn't enter any input so there is validation in form.

> Just disable close button until form is not valid.

Check out this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VVW6J2LqeQvP7kOhr1cd?p=preview)

You can refer more here in doc of [ng-dialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog).

Comment: Can i have an example for it ?

Comment: It all has some mistakes right...bcoz when ever i open add form the pop up is coming.and its evn getting closed even if we does write into the input nd and save button is clicked

Comment: @VindyaVeer Check out edited answer. Changed explanation of answerer NetSonu.

Comment: can someone tell me how to disable the esc key-press too?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way of having control over ngDialog via buttons is to change the default boolean of closeByDocument and showClose to false. Then you can only use buttons to exit.